# Where is the -j (select job) option when using p4 submit?

Tags: perforce

When submitting changelists in Perforce I need to allocate a job. The jobs which I am supposed to associate with my changelist are not allocated to me and does not show up in the list of available jobs when I invoke "p4 submit". I know the job number which I am going to use, but can't find a way to specify it. Basically, I want to do something like:

p4 submit -j

But there is no -j option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a numbered pending changelist, and attach jobs (p4 fix) to that.

I don't think there's a one shot way of submitting the default changelist with an arbitrary job.

Answer (score 2):

In your change spec (when you do p4 submit or p4 change) simply add a Jobs: section with a newline separated list of jobs you wish to fix.

If you edit your user (p4 user) and add a jobview: section, the jobs section will appear automatically.

See http://kb.perforce.com/?article=052